# Application of the Poisson distribution

Tags: probability

I'm having trouble with two exercises of similar kind (I think), both seeing why they're solved a certain way, and the solution itself.

> Allan uses CD-R discs of two kinds A and B. From experience he knows that every 20th of the cheaper A-discs is defect while only every 100th B-disc is defect. What is probability that he, having bought 50 discs of each kind, has more than 5 defect discs? (Hint: Use the fact that the sum of independent Poisson-variables is also Poisson distributed. Solution: 0.084.)

First of all it wouldn't dawn upon me to suppose the Poisson distribution is the key here, my first thought was hypergeometric but it can't be used since we're lacking all its parameters. Poisson only dawned on me by exhausting other discrete options. So my first question is really, is there a clever way to "see" that Poisson is key here?
Second, how would one go about solving this? I tried putting $X_A \sim Po(50 \cdot 0.05)$ and $X_B \sim Po(50 \cdot 0.01)$, adding those and summing up to 5, or subtracting that from one, etc, and didn't reach anything close to the solution.

The other question is this:

> Erik (!) has four light bulbs; three are of type A and one of type B. All life spans are independent and exponentially distributed with expected values 100h for A and 200h for B. When Erik needs a new lamp he takes one at random and then takes note that it still works after 200h. What's the probability that Erik picked an A-lamp? (Solution: $3/(3+e)$.)

(sorry, I realize now that the two aren't at all related. I'll try my luck and leave as is...)
When I finally thought I had understood conditioning (for events) I'm slammed with this. My first thought is to calculate $P(type A | lasted at least 200h)$, but that would be mixing events and variables and I don't know how to do that. As for "lasted at least 200h", I specify it that way since the variables are both continuous and thus $P(last exactly 200h)$ would be zero. Anyway, continuing naively like this, I'd do $P(A|>200h) = P(>200h|A)P(A)/(P(>200h|A)P(A)+P(>200h|B)P(B)) = 3P(>200h|A)/(3P(>200h|A)+P(>200h|B))$, with $P(A)=3/4$ and $P(B)=1/4$. This looks suspiciously similar to the actual solution, except the remaining probabilities cannot possibly be 1 and e, respectively. So close, yet so far. So, how would one do here, I'm completely lost.

EDIT: My ansatz in the second question was apparently correct after all. But I'm still not convinced of the method I used, had I not had the actual answer I would never have arrived at the answer.

Comment: Please do not post two different questions as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As zhoraster mentioned, please post a single question at a time.  That being said, I'm going to try to answer both and hope it doesn't become a habit for either of us :)

1)  I would not have thought of the hypergeometric here - you know $P($type $A$ is a defect$) = 1/20$ and $P($type $B$ is a defect$) = 1/100$, where all variables are independent.  The question asks whether in 50 trials of each we expect to have more than 5 "successes" (a success being the occurrence of the event in question, finding a defect).  This number of defects for each type follows a binomial distribution, so letting $X = $# of type $A$ which were defects and $Y = $# of type $B$ which were defects, we can just calculate 
$$1 - P\left( ~ ( X,Y ) \in \{ (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (0,2), (1,1), (2,0), \dots, (5,0) \}\right) $$ 
$$ = 1 - P((X,Y) = (0,0)) - \dots - P((X,Y) = (5,0)). $$
Each of these individual events can easily be calculated, which gives an elementary solution.  The downside to using the simple binomial distribution is that we have to calculate 21 different probabilities to get our answer.

Enter the Poisson distribution.  We know that if we have a small probability of "success," the binomial distribution is well approximated by the Poisson distribution.  For 50 trials each with a $1/20$ chance of success, the Poisson random variable $V$ with parameter $np = 50/20$ is a good approximation.  So $P(X = a) \approx P(V = a) = {(5/2)^a e^{-5/2} \over a!}$.  Defining $W \sim Pois(50/100) = Pois(1/2)$ as the approximant to $Y$, we now have
$$ X+Y \approx V+W = Pois(5/2) + Pois(1/2) \sim Pois(5/2 + 1/2) $$
using the property given in the hint.  Let $Z$ be distributed as $Pois(3)$.  Then the problem boils down to 
$$P(X+Y > 5) \approx P(Z > 5) = 1 - P(Z \leq 5) = 1- \sum_{k = 0}^5 {3^k e^{-3} \over k!} $$
$$ = 1 - e^{-3}(1 + 3 + 9/2 + 27/6 + 81/24 + 243/120) \approx 0.0839. $$

2)  Let $X$ be the event that an $A$ lightbulb lasts over 200 hrs, let $Y$ be the event that a $B$ bulb does.  Your equation is correct, we just need to know
$$ P(X) = {1 \over 100} \int_{200}^{\infty}e^{-x/100}dx = e^{-2} $$
$$ P(Y) = {1 \over 200} \int_{200}^{\infty}e^{-x/200} dx = e^{-1}. $$
Then using Bayes' theorem,
$$P(A | \textrm{ bulb lasts over } 200 hrs) = {3P(X) \over 3P(X) + P(Y)} = {3e^{-2} \over 3e^{-2} + e^{-1}} = {3 \over 3 + e}.$$

Comment: That is a great answer Titus, you really disassembled (1) and reassembled it to reveal the answer. As for (2) I agree with your answer, but I shall have to return with a better formulation of my problem with _why_ that is the answer. Thanks!